# Why cant TWRP boot into recovery mode anymore?

Tags: cyanogenmod, recovery-mode, twrp

I installed cyanogenmode using TWRP and used my MOTO G 2013 without any issues. Used it all afternoon without major problems (let me add that it is a nightly version) After a few hours I decided to create a backup file and then reboot the phone. Now it is stuck at the logo screen and it wont even let me use the recovery mode. What can be the issue?

Comment: Maybe because it is nightly? See this http://android.stackexchange.com/a/132046/131553

Comment: @beeshyams yeah...you are right. It had to be the fact that it messed something up. I use Ubuntu...so using these three commands:
fastboot erase system

Comment: @beeshyams It had to be the nightly that messed something up. I use Ubuntu...and using these three commands below, I cleaned my Moto G from the terminal:
sudo fastboot erase system,
sudo fastboot erase data,
sudo fastboot erase cache (I seriously dont know if I needed all three..oh and sudo was necessary since my phone lost the root access)...

Then using the terminal I reinstalled the recovery (twrp). 
Then I wiped the whole thing again and installed the stable version of cyanogemod.